# Prevent floating point overflows right before they happen

Tags: common-lisp

As an easy way to overflow a floating point (I'm using double floats in my code, so I'll do so here as well):

```
(setq *read-default-float-format* 'double-float)
(defun example-float-overflow (x)
  (example-float-overflow (* x x)))
(example-float-overflow 4.4)
```

Very quickly, x grows larger and larger. Pretty soon it reaches 5.295234290518905e164 and overflows. Which, is that even a double float anymore?

Anyway, what is the best way to identify the point right before it overflows? Right now I'm doing something like:

```
(defun example-float-overflow-no-error (x)
  (if (> (* x x) 1.0e20)
      x
      (example-float-overflow-no-error (* x x))))
(example-float-overflow 4.4)
```

=> 1.973525870240772e10

Note: I'm not actually interested in the result, but the rest of my code depends on it to run as many times as it can before overflowing.

Comment: You can test whether `x` is greater than `(sqrt most-positive-double-float)`.

Comment: Why not use a condition handler to detect the overflow when it happens?

Comment: Which condition handler would you use?

Comment: handle the `FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW` condition.

Comment: You could probably use `HANDLER-CASE` to return `NIL` when the error occurs.

Comment: Turns out double float goes up to 1.7976931348623157e308.

Comment: Good advice. I was trying to avoid using code like this in order to make it as efficient as possible. Hoping someone has run into this and has a trick up their sleeve.

Comment: The limit is implementation-dependent. That's why you need to use a `MOST-POSITIVE-DOUBLE-FLOAT` to determine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barmar [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614435/prevent-floating-point-overflows-right-before-they-happen#comment47374422_29614435) handling the **floating-point-overflow** condition just after the overflow occurs.  This is a little bit than detecting when it is about to occur, but it's probably the easiest thing to do.  For instance, here's an **add** function that adds just like **+**, except that if something goes wrong, you can use the **use-value** restart to provide a different value:

```
(defun add (&rest numbers)
  "Add numbers with +, but with a USE-VALUE restart
available in case of an overflow (or other condition)."
  (restart-case (reduce '+ numbers)
    (use-value (value &optional condition) value)))
```

Then you can establish **use-value** restarts that can be used to provide a value if a call to **add** fails:

```
;; Attempt to some arithmetic, but with a handler bound that
;; will return 42 if an floating point-overflow occurs.
(handler-bind ((floating-point-overflow
                (lambda (condition)
                  (use-value 42 condition))))
  (+ 5 (add most-positive-double-float most-positive-double-float)))
;;     |----------- this ends up evaluating to 42 ---------------|
;;|------------- and 42 + 5 is 47 --------------------------------|
;=> 47
```