# Trouble running Common Music in Emacs

Tags: bash, git, emacs, common-lisp, sbcl

I am a 4th year bachelor student composition who recently came across the GitHub [repositories](https://github.com/ormf/cm) of Prof. Orm Finnendahl. I was wondering if anyone could help me setup Common Music 2.12.0 with Emacs on Windows 7, 64 bit. I’m embarrassed to say I have been trying on and off now for a couple of months and just can’t figure it out! I’ve read CM’s documentation, but it simply doesn’t seem to work.

I’ve tried following the instructions on the [older website](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm2/doc/cm.html) dedicated to CM2 (prior to CM3). Specifically these two links: "[Installing Common Music](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm2/doc/install.html)", and "[Running Common Music in Emacs](http://commonmusic.sourceforge.net/cm2/doc/emacs.html)". I did get the Emacs part right, I think, but Bash gives an error trying to load anything.

*(I put the cm-master without the -master, and other repositories in C:/Users/XI-USER/lispmusic)*

1. My Emacs is, I believe properly setup, as follows in the init file (the last lines are from the "Running Common Music in Emacs" website):

```el
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(load (expand-file-name "~/quicklisp/slime-helper.el"))
(setq inferior-lisp-program "sbcl")

(global-linum-mode t)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'highlight-numbers-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-quoted-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-defined-mode)

(use-package kaolin-themes
  :config
  (load-theme 'kaolin-galaxy t))

;; If t, enable italic style in comments.
(setq kaolin-themes-italic-comments t)

;; When t, will display colored hl-line style instead monochrome.    
(setq kaolin-themes-hl-line-colored t)      

;; Enable distinct background for fringe and line numbers.
(setq kaolin-themes-distinct-fringe t)  

;; Enable distinct colors for company popup scrollbar.
(setq kaolin-themes-distinct-company-scrollbar t)

;; Show git-gutter indicators as solid lines
(setq kaolin-themes-git-gutter-solid t)

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (use-package)))
 '(tool-bar-mode nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:family "Victor Mono" :foundry "outline" :slant normal :weight bold :height 120 :width normal)))))

(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/XI-USER/.slime/")
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Users/XI-USER/lispmusic/cm/")
(load "etc/emacs/cm.el")
(enable-cm-commands)
```

2. I have both Git Bash and cygwin64 installed (I believe Bash is 64 bit too, should it matter)
3. When I load cm/bin/cm.sh via Emacs shell, I get this error message in Bash:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-INT:SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10027900C3}>:
  Couldn't load "/c/Users/XI-USER/lispmusic/cm/bin/../src/cm.lisp": file does
  not exist.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [CONTINUE] Ignore runtime option --eval "(progn (load \"/c/Users/XI-USER/lispmusic/cm/bin/../src/cm.lisp\" :verbose nil) (cm))".
  1: [ABORT   ] Skip rest of --eval and --load options.
  2:            Skip to toplevel READ/EVAL/PRINT loop.
  3: [EXIT    ] Exit SBCL (calling #'EXIT, killing the process).

(LOAD "/c/Users/XI-USER/lispmusic/cm/bin/../src/cm.lisp" :VERBOSE NIL :PRINT NIL :IF-DOES-NOT-EXIST T :EXTERNAL-FORMAT :DEFAULT)
0]
```

4. And nothing via cygwin64 (black DOS screen starts up and closes immediately)
5. I get these type of errors trying to load CM in Emacs:
   **M-x cm ->** "*Wrong type argument: stringp, nil*"
   and **CL-USER> (in-package :cm) ->** "*The name "CM" does not designate any package.
   [Condition of type SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR]*"
6. Interestingly, when (and only when) I start up slime, and then type C-c C-d c the CM find dictionary does work!

Comment: For ""The name "CM" does not designate any package" that means Slime doesn't know where CM is. You can clone it to `~/quicklisp/local-projects`, then `(ql:quickload :cm)` (if you installed Quicklisp). Or run `slime-compile-and-load-file` (C-c C-k) in `cm.asd`. https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/getting-started.html#working-with-projects

Comment: If you want an Emacs that is sure to work, see Portacle: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html

Comment: Dear Ehvince, your answer has brought me closer than ever! Sadly, when I `(ql:quickload :cm)` I get the following error: `arithmetic error FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW signalled
   [Condition of type FLOATING-POINT-OVERFLOW]`, and atleast 5 possible 'Restarts' options. For example, `0: [TRY-RECOMPILING] Recompile scales and try loading it again` and `1: [RETRY] Retry loading FASL for #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "cm" "src" "scales">.` (so it seems to have something to do with the scales.lisp file in the src folder)

Comment: This is what it says in slime: `CL-USER> (ql:quickload :cm)
To load "cm":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    cm
; Loading "cm"
To load "fomus":
  Install 1 Quicklisp release:
    fomus
; Fetching #<URL "http://beta.quicklisp.org/archive/fomus/2012-09-09/fomus-20120909-svn.tgz">

; Loading "fomus"
[package fomus]...
...
...

;; FOMUS v0.2.28
;; Lisp music notation formatter
;; Copyright (c) David Psenicka

......
[package fomus-notepro]...
[package fomus-timedump]; 
 ; compilation unit finished
 ;   Undefined function:
 ;    FOMUS::SAVE-XML
 ;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition`

Comment: These seem real CM bugs that you should open an issue for. If you want to bypass the undefined function error you could write a dummy `save-xml` function inside the `fomus` package and see how the rest goes.

Comment: The debugger should tell exactly where the error appears. You can also press `v` to go to the problematic line. And give that info in the issues, or write a `handler-case` around the function and see how it goes…https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614435/prevent-floating-point-overflows-right-before-they-happen

Comment: When I press `v` I get this message: `Error: The value #<SB-DI::BOGUS-DEBUG-FUN "bogus stack frame"> is not of type SB-DI::COMPILED-DEBUG-FUN`. I wonder if the problem could be that I am trying to run a 32 bit program with a 64 bit version of Emacs?